# Using Delphi Subversion integration to check files in from another folder

Tags: delphi, svn, version-control, delphi-ide

So we're converting from VSS to delphi and we use a lot of include paths.

We'd like to at least attempt to conform to whatever the Delphi IDE decides is the right way to do this, but it's non-obvious.

Apparently, you can't include files in SVN that are used in a different folder, even if they are mentioned in the project group.

So... what is the expectation? Do we have to convert all our files to use namespaces and put them in the same folder just to use Delphi's subversion integration completely?

Should we create BPL's for all of our 'unprojected' common files that are shared between multiple DLLs?

Comment: Have you checked the 'externals' feature in Subversion? It would be possible to reference external folders as a subversion property, and the referenced folder and files will be checked out in a sub folder of the project. This would require more disk space, but there would be only one master version of the referenced files.

Comment: Original poster what do you mean; (1) other directory in same repository, or (2) directory in other repository? If (2) then njn should convert his comment into an answer.

Comment: @mjn, I hadn't heard of externals, but I'm finding out about it.

Comment: additional note: for better control, the TortoiseSVN commit dialog visually separates the external files so it is easy to see when a commit will affect "common" files. I am not sure if the Delphi IDE plugin does something similar (but it is essential to prevent accidental commits of files which may be referenced in many other projects).

Comment: @marco it's all one repository, the problem seems to be (and I didn't know this when asking the question) that subversion delphi integration only seems to work when the DPR is in the root directory, or the whole thing is checked in from a bpg which is in the root directory of the files to be checked in.